# Provider org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.CartesianAuthorityFactory could not be instantiated

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, geotools

I'm using the maven-shade-plugin to package GeoTools packages into my uber Jar:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>this.is.my.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>launcher</shadedClassifierName>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

The service works when the JAR is built and run in a docker-compose environment, but when I run the service in Netbeans I get several exceptions:

```
Dec 09, 2020 8:04:53 AM org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry scanForPlugins
WARNING: Can't load a service for category "CRSAuthorityFactory". Cause is "ServiceConfigurationError: org.opengis.referencing.crs.CRSAuthorityFactory: Provider org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.CartesianAuthorityFactory could not be instantiated".
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.opengis.referencing.crs.CRSAuthorityFactory: Provider org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.CartesianAuthorityFactory could not be instantiated

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: UNIT

Dec 09, 2020 8:04:53 AM org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry scanForPlugins
WARNING: Can't load a service for category "CRSAuthorityFactory". Cause is "ServiceConfigurationError: org.opengis.referencing.crs.CRSAuthorityFactory: Provider org.geotools.referencing.factory.wms.AutoCRSFactory could not be instantiated".
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.opengis.referencing.crs.CRSAuthorityFactory: Provider org.geotools.referencing.factory.wms.AutoCRSFactory could not be instantiated

Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/geotools/referencing/factory/AuthorityFactoryAdapter.missingFactory(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/opengis/referencing/FactoryException; @25: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/opengis/referencing/NoSuchAuthorityCodeException' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/opengis/referencing/FactoryException' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @25
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/geotools/referencing/factory/AuthorityFactoryAdapter', 'java/lang/Class', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { 'org/opengis/referencing/NoSuchAuthorityCodeException' }
```

And so on.

My pom contains:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
    <version>24.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-referencing</artifactId>
    <version>24.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

The maven dependency tree related to GeoTools is:

```
[INFO] +- org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:24.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ejml:ejml-ddense:jar:0.34:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ejml:ejml-core:jar:0.34:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:24.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:24.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- systems.uom:systems-common:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- tech.units:indriya:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- tech.uom.lib:uom-lib-common:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- si.uom:si-quantity:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- si.uom:si-units:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.geotools.ogc:net.opengis.ows:jar:24.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.geotools.ogc:org.w3.xlink:jar:24.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.common:jar:2.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore:jar:2.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi:jar:2.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- it.geosolutions.jgridshift:jgridshift-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.geographiclib:GeographicLib-Java:jar:1.49:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.media:jai_core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:jar:24.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.geotools:gt-epsg-extension:jar:24.0:compile
```

The code being executed is:

```
sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
```

Edit: I forgot to say that I'm running Fedora 31 running OpenJDK 11. Netbeans is configured to use OpenJDK 1.8 as the default platform. This may be a problem due to class loaders?

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Having rebuilt the JARs and docker images, it doesn't work in the docker-compose environment either. Hmm.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an actual implementation of the referencing code. From the [FAQ](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/faq.html):

> ### Q: How to choose an EPSG Authority?
>
> The referencing module does not do very much out  of the box - it
> needs someone to tell it what all the funny codes mean (such as
> “EPSG:4326”).
>
> You need to choose a single EPSG jar to have on your classpath; if you
> have several EPSG jars on your classpath you will get a
> FactoryException.
>
> For most needs just use the gt-epsg-hsql plugin:
>
> - gt-epsgh-hsql: will unpack an HSQL database containing the official
>   EPSG database into a temp directory, a great solution for desktop
>   applications.
>
> There are several alternatives:
>
> - gt-epsg-wkt: uses an internal property file and is lightweight rather
>   than official and correct. A great solution for applets
> - gt-epsg-postgres: uses the official EPSG database which you have to
>   load into PostgreSQL yourself. A great solution for Java EE
>   applications.
> - gt-epsg-access: directly use an the official EPSG database as
>   distributed. A great solution for windows users that need the latest
>   official database.
>
> #### Unsupported:
>
> - gt-epsg-oracle: Load the official EPSG database into oracle to use
>   this plugin
> - gt-epsgh-h2: use this popular pure java database

Comment: Am I not doing that with the pom fragment I posted? It pulls in this dependency: org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:jar:24.0:compile?

Comment: sorry missed that, should be working - may be you also need `gt-main` I always need it but it depends on your exact code usually

Comment: Thanks. I'll try gt-main, but I wonder if it's something related to a class loader - I have OpenJDK 8 and 11 on my system.

Comment: might be related to java 11 modules, try java 8 and see if that fixed

Comment: mvn -version gives 1.8.0_272, while javac -version gives 11.0.9. Maybe that's an issue. I have both JDKs installed and I'm using the toolchain plugin.

Comment: I ported this project to Java 11, but I'm maintaining an older project that uses Java 8.

Comment: Could well be this https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6709

Comment: I ported the project back to JDK8 and I added `gt-main` but that didn't help. I still have OpenJDK11 installed.

Comment: Next, I would try 24.1 and make sure I was building and running with JDK-8. Failing that try to make a minimal example and post it to a bug report

Comment: I built a minimal example using GeoTools 18.4 and it runs without any exceptions. So...... Hmmm.

Comment: There were changes to units between 18 and 24 so that is probable

Comment: I ported my Java project back to JDK 1.8 and GeoTools 18.4 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't that interesting. I modified my pom.xml to move the geotools dependencies before my application dependencies and it worked. I didn't realise the ordering of dependencies in pom.xml was iomportant.

Comment: It shouldn't be - are you making a fat jar?

Comment: I am, using maven-shade-plugin (see original post above).

Comment: it's possible that the shade jar builder is messing up the serviceSPI entries, not sure how to test that though